# Silverlight ChildWindow with asp.net masterpage

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, childwindow

I'm using silverlight with asp.net.i have added silverlight content to asp.net master page using following code

```
<div style="width:200px">
     <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
             type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" style="height: 1000px">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightSummary.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

in the silverlight MainPage.xaml i have a button and when click on the button it opens a ChildWindow.

```
 private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopUpWindow PPW = new PopUpWindow();
            PPW.chart1.DataContext = App.Current.Resources["ChartResult"];

            PPW.Show();
        }
```

issue is the child window shows only in masterpage,its not covering the whole screen with the asp.net master page and the content page.how can i make it to show the childWindow on ful screen

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're asking, is for the Silverlight to perform "blocking" on the entire page, when only the sub content (i.e., the silverlight object) is being hosted in a fraction of the page.  Theoretically, a silverlight app can only perform blocking to on the entire object which represents it.  That object is being held in that "div", so at best case, it can only block up to to that div.  Outside of that it can only communicate with other elements via messages, but it cannot provide the overlay/blocking you seek.  So the answer is to look at the problem from another angle (it is possible to solve this issue...)..(Ignore the sad solutions)

What are your options?

**Sad Solutions:**
 - Include all the items you wish to block in the silverlight control and not on the aspx page
 - Put the entire app in silverlight...not really feasible

**Real Solutions**
 - If it's an image you wish to show, render the image to a temporary sub directory of the aspx site,  define a javascript function to perform blocking on the page by displaying a light box, then invoke that javascript button from silverlight (you're best bet).
 - If it's text or other, use a similar technique as the aforementioned option.
 - When the lightbox from javascript or so is closed, invoke a silverlight method (if neccessary) to refresh the silverlight object.

The example of how to communicate back and forth between silverlight and javascript is in another post i've answered. Here - [ASP.NET MVC to Silverlight Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390412/asp-net-mvc-to-silverlight-communication/9433593#9433593)